# How to reset my WP8?

Tags: 8.0

How do I reset back to my old OS WP8 Apollo (8.0.9903.10) and cancel update that was happened

Comment: Why would you want to cancel the update? did something go wrong during the update process or you just don't like the changes in the update? It is not possible to uninstall updates or to do a rollback. your only option is to have it flashed by Nokia (which they won't do probably)

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that using the phone itself. Either visit a service center or flash it yourself using (Nokia Software Updater for Retail).